# Debian Stretch mount hybrid iso fails

Tags: debian, mount, iso

I try to mount the current Debian live ISO (debian-live-9.3.0-amd64-xfce.iso from https://cdimage.debian.org/debian-cd/current-live/amd64/bt-hybrid/) in a Debian 9.3.0 system.

The command should be something like

```
sudo mount -o loop debian-live-9.3.0-amd64-xfce.iso /mnt
```

But unfortunately this gives me the error

```
mount: /dev/loop0: can't read superblock
```

I tried to load the ISO several times and I checked the md5 code.
After some googling I found out, that this could be a fs problem. So I called

```
cat /proc/filesystems
```

and received

```
nodev   sysfs
nodev   rootfs
nodev   ramfs
nodev   bdev
nodev   proc
nodev   cpuset
nodev   cgroup
nodev   cgroup2
nodev   tmpfs
nodev   devtmpfs
nodev   debugfs
nodev   tracefs
nodev   securityfs
nodev   sockfs
nodev   bpf
nodev   pipefs
nodev   hugetlbfs
nodev   devpts
nodev   pstore
nodev   mqueue
        ext3
        ext2
        ext4
nodev   autofs
nodev   vboxsf
nodev   rpc_pipefs
        xfs
        jfs
        msdos
        vfat
        ntfs
        minix
        hfs
        hfsplus
        qnx4
        ufs
        btrfs
        fuseblk
nodev   fuse
nodev   fusectl
        iso9660
```

Is there something missing?

I also tried to specify the fs:

```
sudo mount -o loop -t iso9660 debian-live-9.3.0-amd64-xfce.iso /mnt
```

But this gives me the error

```
mount: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/loop0,
       missing codepage or helper program, or other error

       In some cases useful info is found in syslog - try
       dmesg | tail or so.
```

Then I tried:

```
sudo dmesg |tail
```

And received:

```
[ 5658.879475] Buffer I/O error on dev loop0, logical block 1901889, async page read
[ 5658.879477] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev loop0, sector 3803780
[ 5658.879478] Buffer I/O error on dev loop0, logical block 1901890, async page read
[ 5658.879480] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev loop0, sector 3803782
[ 5658.879482] Buffer I/O error on dev loop0, logical block 1901891, async page read
[ 6301.201338] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev loop0, sector 3803776
[ 6301.201350] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev loop0, sector 3803776
[ 6301.201353] Buffer I/O error on dev loop0, logical block 475472, async page read
[ 6301.201746] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev loop0, sector 64
[ 6301.201812] isofs_fill_super: bread failed, dev=loop0, iso_blknum=16, block=32
```

I faced the same problem, when trying to mount debian-9.3.0-amd64-netinst.iso from the official download site.

Just to be sure I installed Debian 8.10.0 and mounting works.
To be sure, that my running Debian is not broken in some way, I installed a fresh 9.3.0 and it did not work again.

So it seems to me, that they changed something, so my question is:

What can I do to mount the Debian live ISO using the mount command?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? (Other than mounting the ISO.)

Comment: there's one similar question [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/862482/why-cant-i-mount-an-image-i-just-created-on-loopback/862484#862484), though it doesn't seem to clarify anything for me.  The answer suggests the IO errors are "real".  However... I don't think `mount -oloop` uses direct IO, therefore you would expect to see similar errors for your hard drive - `sda` or such - somewhere, as well as for `loop0`.

Comment: @arochester I wrote a script, that creates a persistent live stick. The script worked for me until i think Debian 9.0.0 or 9.1.0 or something. Now something was changed, so it does not work anymore.